# Why is there no posix_spawn manpage on my system (14.04) & how do I get it installed?

Tags: package-management, manpage

Why is there no [posix_spawn](https://linux.die.net/man/3/posix_spawn) manpage on my system  (14.04)  & how do I get it installed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install the package `manpages-posix-dev`